# How to convert pandas groups into different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like below.

```
unit time s1 s2 ....
1    1    2  3
1    2    4  5
1    3    9  7
2    1    5  2
2    2    3  1
```

I would like to group data by units, keep the minimum similar number of last observations based on time (unit 2 has 2 observations), and make a separate group for the s1 column. So, something like below.

```
unit_1 unit_2 
   4      5 
   9      3
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping 'last minimum similar number of last overvations' ? Why is the unit 1, s1 value of 2 discarded? You need max 2 values? Or you want the last 2 values based on time?

Comment: I want last 2 values based on time. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Changed it.

Comment: Also, can u show what happens to s2 in the example of the output? Do you make separate rows? or columns?

Comment: I would like to discard it. I want to compute the correlation among the same column of different groups. So, I would do similar procedure for s2 in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem -

```
def f(col):
    #First step is to get the last 2 for each group using .tail(2)
    dff = df[['unit','time',col]].sort_values(by=['unit','time'],axis=0).groupby(['unit']).tail(2)

    #Next we need the ordered rank of the time values instead of the actual values of time, 
    #since then we can keep the time values 2,3 as 1,2 and 1,2 as 1,2.
    dff['time'] = dff.groupby(['unit']).rank()

    #Last we pivot over the time and units to get the columns that you need for correlation analysis
    dff = dff.pivot(index='time',columns='unit',values=col).reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix('unit_')
    return dff

f('s1')
```

```
unit    unit_1  unit_2
   0         4       5
   1         9       3
```

Use this function for a faster runtime.

```
def f(col):
    filt = df[['unit',col]].groupby('unit').tail(2)  #filter last 2
    filt['count'] = filt.groupby('unit').cumcount()  #add a counter column for pivot
    
    #Use counter column as index and unit as column for pivot, then add prefix
    filt = filt.pivot(index='count',columns='unit',values=col).reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix("unit_")
    return filt
```

Answer (score 1):

`Groupby` unit and pass the list of the `nth` values.Drop unwanted columns. Transpose dataframe and add prefix unit to the names. Transpose and ravel to combine columns

```
   g= df.groupby('unit', group_keys=False).nth([-1,-2]).drop(columns=['time','s2']).T.add_prefix('unit_')#.unstack('s1')

final = pd.DataFrame({'unit_1': g['unit_1'].values.T.ravel(),
                    'unit_2': g['unit_2'].values.T.ravel()})
final

    unit_1  unit_2
0       4       5
1       9       3
```

Comment: can you change ".apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2:])" instead of ".nlargest(2)"?

Comment: This is incorrect as it returns only the largest values in s1.. not based on time. The iloc will help though. that should fix it.

Comment: Your second solution works, but the first one just yields the same result as ```df.groupby(['unit'])['unit','s1'].tail(2)```

Answer (score 1):

So, I made this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'units': [1,1,1,2,2], 's1':[2,4,9,5,3]})

new_df = df.groupby('units').tail(2) # Taking the last 2 values
new_df
Out:
     units s1
    1   1   4
    2   1   9
    3   2   5
    4   2   3


units_list = new_df.units.unique() # How many units do we have?
units_columns = [] # For col names
form_dict = {}
# We have 2 values for each unit, so the number of elements is 2n, 
# where n is a number of unit corresponding the new_df.
n = 0

for unit in units_list:
    units_columns.append('unit_{}'.format(unit))

while n != len(new_df['s1']):
    for col in units_columns:
        form_dict.update({col:new_df['s1'][n:n+2].values})
        n += 2
        
final_df = pd.DataFrame(form_dict)
final_df
```

And the result is:

```
 unit_1 unit_2
0   4   5
1   9   3
```